# Android Database SQLite or MySQL?

Tags: android, database

I am new to Android Development and I'm developing an application for my Final Year Project.

I am a little confused as to when it comes to setting up the database. I read a few things and most people seem to use SQLite.

Basically I am developing an android app which has too different aspects to it.
1. admin inputs data on the app and saves to a database. 2. users open app and view data from the database.
The data is going to have to be input and viewable over the 3g/wifi network.

Do i need to host my database online and which database would be best to use? from reading it seems SQLite is hosted on your local disk so should i use MySQL? 
Any help would be grately appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android includes SQLite. So, if you save data in a DB on an Android system itself, you use SQLite. If you store your data elsewhere, you are free to use whatever you like, Oracle, DB2, Mysql or even SQLite.